# is it possible to create an object file from other object files in gcc?

Tags: gcc, makefile, linker

I was trying to do something like this in a makefile:

```
program.exe: ui.o main.o
   gcc ......etc
ui.o: window1.o window2.o
   gcc -c window1.o window2.o -o ui.o #this doesn't want to work
window1.o: window1.c window1.h window1_events.c window1_controls.c ...
   gcc -c window1.c window1_events.c window1_controls.c... -o window1.o
window2.o: ...
   gcc ...
main.o: ...
   gcc ...
```

but when I compile like this, it gives the error "input file unused because linking not done," and then I get a bunch of unresolved externs, etc--problems which are resolved by changing

```
program.exe: ui.o main.o
   gcc ...
```

to

```
program.exe: window1.o window2.o main.o
   gcc ...
```

so is it possible to just link object files together, to avoid having mile-long lines in a makefile and break down the build process a little more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [combine two GCC compiled .o object files into a third .o file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980102/combine-two-gcc-compiled-o-object-files-into-a-third-o-file)

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视 this question was asked a year before the linked one. It's also over six years old.

Comment: Consensus is that upvotes are more important than age. Questions are useful forever, so being old does not mean it should not be closed. Peace s2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I bunch of object files is a library. You can create a library with the [ar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ar) 
utility. The following example creates a library called mylib.a containing the files foo.o and bar.o

```
ar rvs mylib.a foo.o bar.o
```

You can then link with it by using it on the compiler command line:

```
gcc -o myexe main.c mylib.a
```

Answer (score 20):

Yes: to merge several object files into one, use `ld -r` or `ld -Ur`:

From "man ld" on Linux:

```
   -r
   --relocatable
      Generate  relocatable  output---i.e.,  generate  an output file that can
      in turn serve as input to ld.  This is often called partial linking.
      As a side effect, in environments that support standard Unix magic
      numbers, this option also sets the output file’s magic number to
      "OMAGIC".
      If this option is not specified, an absolute file is produced.
      When linking C++ programs, this option will not resolve references to
      constructors;  to do that, use -Ur.
```

You could also do this with gcc:

```
gcc -Wl,-r foo.o bar.o -o foobar.o -nostdlib
```

Merging object files like this has some advantages over using an archive library: if merged files change very infrequently (compared to say main.c), your final executable links will be faster.

OTOH, with archived library, the linker will only use what it needs, so your executable may end up being smaller if e.g. window2.c ends up not being necessary.

Answer (score 2):

To create a library:

```
ar rvs somelib.a file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

To link it:

```
gcc -o program.exe file4.o somelib.a
```