# Link a static lib into a shared lib?

Tags: c++, linux, static, g++, shared

Background:

I want to link a few static libs into a shared lib. The reason is that I want my application to use the specific lib versions that I have tested it with. I do not want to ship the static versions as shared libraries with my application. I have created this sample lib and application to simplify as much as possible. I would like to continue to link the shared lib to the application during linking.

Question:

Why do I get the error messages listed below? What am I doing wrong? Perhaps this is not the usual way of doing things on linux, but is it possible to do so? Is this boost specific?

---- library

```
//example.cpp
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
void doit()
{
    boost::thread t1;
}

#build script
g++ -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include -c example.cpp -o example.o
g++ -shared /usr/lib/libboost_thread.a /usr/lib/libboost_system.a 
    example.o -o libexample.so
#build OK.
```

---- sample application

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
void doit();
int main()
{
    std::cout << "main\n";
    doit();
    return 0;
};

#build script.
g++ -Wall -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ libexample.so main.o -o main

#error message.
libexample.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread::thread()'
libexample.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread::~thread()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

All source code is located in the same directory. Boost is installed in /usr/lib and /usr/include. Boost, version 1.40, was installed using apt-get on a ubuntu 10.04 machine.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't do that: static libraries usually contain plain object members, while shared libraries contain position independent code.

Comment: But what if I recompile the static libs with -fPIC? Would that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way for you is to use the `--whole-archive` linker switch (there are more SO questions on this topic, see one here [how to link static library into dynamic library in gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649735/how-to-link-static-library-into-dynamic-library-in-gcc) ).

The downside of that is that your shared library will export all symbols from the Boost static libraries and you might have weird issues if you'll use your `.so` in an application that also uses Boost (but a different version or compiled with different switches).

So you need to use a version script to hide what's exported from the library (see [How to hide the exported symbols name within a shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648655/how-to-hide-the-exported-symbols-name-within-a-shared-library) , also google for linker version scripts), leaving only `doit()` visible. In your case, such a version script could look like:

```
{
global:
    doit*;
local:
    *;
}
```

You also need to make sure that the static libraries you're linking with are compiled with `-fPIC` (which is unlikely, if you didn't tweak their build flags), other wise you'll have a performance penalty on `i386` and might not link at all on `amd64`.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. I just have to download and recompile boost first.

Comment: This answer goes a bit further in explaining: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2649792/602340