# Building shared library from static libraries

Tags: c++, boost, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I've written some code that works as a wrapper around `boost::asio` and I am looking for a way to pack it as a shared object (.so), to be used by some applications I'm working on, however I would like to remove all dependencies from the boost libraries (mainly because they were custom compiled, and may cause conflict with default pre-built boost libraries). I'm linking my code to the static versions of these special boost libraries, however, the linker provides the following error:

```
g++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -I/path_to_boost_headers -Wall -fPIC -o build/obj.o -c include/source.cpp 
g++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -shared -Wl,-soname,libobj.so.1 -o lib/libobj.so.1 build/obj.o -lc /project_path/lib/libboost_serialization.a /project_path/lib/libboost_wserialization.a /project_path/lib/libboost_system.a
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joao/Work/ASBG/code/cpp/extra/socket/lib/libboost_system.a(error_code.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I'm not mistaken, boost libraries are compiled with `-fPIC` by default. Even so, I added the flag when compiling boostand replaced the libraries: same output.

Comment: *Static* boost libraries are not compiled with `-fPIC` by default. Static
libraries conventionally aren't. Your attempt to build unconventional static boost libraries of PIC objects has evidently failed, but without knowing the nature of that attempt one can't tell why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put `-Wl,--whole-archive` and `-Wl,--no-whole-archive` around the static libraries.

Untested, but something like this could work:

```
g++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -shared -Wl,-soname,libobj.so.1 \
  -o lib/libobj.so.1 build/obj.o -lc \
  -Wl,--whole-archive \
  /project_path/lib/libboost_serialization.a \
  /project_path/lib/libboost_wserialization.a \
  /project_path/lib/libboost_system.a \
  -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Notes:

- The `--whole-archive` option forces the linker to look at all symbols and not just at unresolved ones. On Linux, there is the concept of weak and strong symbols. I have written an explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45271521/783510).
- I think [Link a static lib into a shared lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13108004/783510) is very similar to your problem.

(Also be aware that mixing dynamically and shared libraries is probably not a good idea. You may end up with the combined disadvantages, which goes against your idea of simplification. However, I do not know the whole picture. Just an opinion.)