# Is mixing dynamic and shared libraries a good idea when creating an ODBC Driver?

Tags: gcc, odbc, static-linking, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

I am creating an ODBC driver (which is, by nature, distributed as a shared library) and don't want the users to have to find and install all of the dependencies.

Looking at how I might statically link a `.so` shared library with its dependencies, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362557/13564565) which gives a solution which reads in part:

> (Also be aware that mixing dynamically and shared libraries is probably not a good idea. You may end up with the combined disadvantages, which goes against your idea of simplification. However, I do not know the whole picture. Just an opinion.)

Is this a good use case for following the instructions in the answer and statically linking the shared library's dependencies?

Comment: A shared library *is* a dynamic library. The author of the answer you
have quoted from made a typo: they meant to say "... mixing static and shared libraries is probably not a good idea", or else "...mixing dynamic and static libraries...". If you care to change the word "dynamic" to "static" in your question title
and also indicate the typo after you quote from the other post, you will likely get
some answers. As it is, people think that the question does not make sense.