# 'undefined reference to function' while trying to build a program with header that redefines function names

Tags: c, function, elf

I'm having the exact same problem as a person that asked this question: [How to hide the exported symbols name within a shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648655/how-to-hide-the-exported-symbols-name-within-a-shared-library)

I decided to follow instructions given by Alexander (3rd answer) but after including a generated header to my main program in C, i get the error undefined reference to function

head.h

```c
#define SecretFunc1 abab
```

application.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "head.h"

int main(){
    SecretFunc1();
    return 0;   
}
```

libdyn.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int SecretFunc1(){
    return 2
}
```

I've built the dynamic library into `.so` file, then after trying to build the app with: 
`gcc app.c -L<path> -ldyn -o sample`
In function main undefined reference to abab

I don't really know what to do.

Comment: If your intention is to "obfuscate" the symbol names as that answer suggests, you need need to include `heah.h` in `libdyn.c` as well, because otherwise `application.c` expects a function named `abab`, while `libdyn.c` provides it as `SecretFunc1`. But I don't see the point of it. Can you clarify? The compiler should also have warned you, that `abab` is implicitly declared in `application.c`. You should provide an explicit declaration for it.

Comment: It's for the excercise I got. I need to change a specific library symbols names so that you cannot tell what they do, after reading elf tables.

Comment: It is unclear what your exercise requires you to achieve specifically. In particular it is unclear what is given to you and what you should submit as a solution.

Comment: include `"head.h"` also in the implementation.... if you don't you are actually implementing `SecretFunction`, not `abab`

Comment: Implementing a shared object with scrambled names is a bet to project crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After (partial) preprocessing, your `application.c` would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    abab();
    return 0;   
}
```

This should, first of all, give you a warning, that `abab` is declared implicitly, which usually is not a good idea. You should declare the function (in a header file shared by `application.c` and `libdyn.c`):

```
int SecretFunc1(void);
```

When compiling to an object file, this object file will have a reference to the symbol `abab`.

After compiling `libdyn.c` to an object file, it will provide a symbol named `SecretFunc1`. Therefore, the linker will not match it to the reference `abab` in `application.o`.

You need to rename the function in all files using it, e.g. by including `head.h` in `libdyn.c` as well or better putting both the renaming macro and the declaration in a `libdyn.h` that is included in both `libdyn.c` and `application.c`.

Comment: Worked, thank you very much for help. Now I understand what was wrong.