# Compile multiple C source fles into a unique object file

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have some C source files and I am using `gcc`. I basically want to compile all of them and create one single object file. When I try:

```
gcc -c src1.c src2.c src3.c -o final.o
```

I get:

```
gcc: cannot specify -o with -c or -S with multiple files
```

If I try:

```
gcc -c src1.c src2.c src3.c
```

I get three different object files. How can I tell `gcc` to compile all files to return one single object file (I also want to specify its name)? Thank you.

Maybe there is another more common approach to this, in this case please tell me.

Comment: Ok, please tell me how...

Comment: Read http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/ and learn about `make`

Comment: BTW, why exactly do you ask?

Comment: subset: object files instead of source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980102/combine-two-gcc-compiled-o-object-files-into-a-third-o-file

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't compile multiple source files into a single object file. An object file is the compiled result of a single source file and its headers (also known as a [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))).

If you want to combine compiled files, it's usually combined into a static library using the [`ar`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ar) command:

```
$ ar cr libfoo.a file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

You can then use this static library when linking, either passing it directly as an object file:

```
$ gcc file4.o libfoo.a -o myprogram
```

Or linking with it as a library with the `-l` flag

```
$ gcc file4.o -L. -lfoo -o myprogram
```

Comment: This means that gcc can't make functions inline across different source files?

Comment: @CrouchingKitten Not the *compiler*, but the *linker* might be able to do some link-time optimizations which might include cross-TU (Translation Unit) inlining.

Comment: Note that the library has to be after the object files when calling `gcc`. `file1.o file2.o libfoo.a` and not `libfoo.a file1.o file2.o`

Answer (score 12):

This is not a usual way to proceed, but you can easily achieve what you want by creating a new `final.c` file with the following content.

```
#include "src1.c"
#include "src2.c"
#include "src3.c"
```

Then you can compile it as follows.

```
gcc -c final.c -o final.o
```

Note that there may be issues, read compilation errors, even if each file compiles successfully when compiled separately. This tend to happen especially with macro definitions and includes, when *merging* your source files into a single one this way.

Answer (score 10):

May be you're looking for this :

```
ld -r src1.o src2.o src3.o -o final.o
```

But its always nice to have them archived, using

`ar rvs libmy.a file1.o file2.o file3.o`

Then use `-lmy` to link.

Comment: Not `src1.c src2.c src3.c` source files for `ld` but `src1.o src2.o src3.o` *object* files!

Answer (score 4):

To combine multiple source files into a single object file (at least since gcc 4.1), use the compiler/linker option  --combine

(edit) later replaced with the compiler option -flto, with linking automatic depending on the compilation state: [Requirements to use flto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688069/requirements-to-use-flto)

Comment: Does not exist ? g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--combine’
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)

Comment: It [was removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804314/gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-combine) in gcc 4.6.

Answer (score 2):

You can always pipe the files to GCC:

```
join file1.c file2.c file3.c | gcc -x c -c -o single.o -
```

Don't forget the option specifying the language, "-x c", which now cannot be deduced from the file extension. You tell GCC to accept input from stdin with the single trailing dash "-".

Note that this is equivalent to compiling a file "final.c" with following contents:

```
#include "file1.c"
#include "file2.c"
#include "file3.c"
```

With

```
gcc -c -o single.o final.c
```

Comment: Beware of name clashes. It will be painful if say file1.c and file2.c declares the same static variable.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to say. This is a missing feature.

Why?

say `cc` can be `clang` or `gcc`

```
cc -c t1.c t2.c (multi-files at once)
```

vs

```
cc -c t1.c 
cc -c t2.c
...
(one by one)
```

What is the difference?

The output .o is same, though the one by one way can specify `-o name` which may useful when you use cc in your customized toolchain.

The difference is performance. Besides the time for starting up cc, if multi files use same set of .h header files(In most case they will). The header files can load once instead of per file.

Header files could be huge if you use several libraries. A typical .pch (pre-compiled-header) file can as large as 10MB.

In real life test on my small project. I combined all .cpp into one .cpp using `#include "others.cpp"` , the compile time reduced from 600 ms to 300 ms.

The c/cpp compiles slow, so this could be so useful to be a feature.

could like

```
cc -c t1.c -o t1.o  t2.c -o t2.o (specify output name per file)
```

or

```
cc -c t1.c  t2.c -o mylib.a (If some one say .o can't be combined
   , then link to a lib in one command line)
```

I hope clang or gcc develop can see this. But not bothering to wait for a fix even they could agreed this opinion.(argue among open source developers can be very hopeless, unless they realize something from self). You can try the method mentioned in other answers like

```
#include "file1.c"
#include "file2.c"
#include "file3.c"
```

Comment: It actually makes sense to reduce disk-usage while compiling, and probably provide a wider in-memory idea for the optimizer to work with. Similarly, 'single header file packers'. Other advantages include the possibilities to build something small/specific without going through Makefiles

Answer (score 0):

Either you make a `final.c` which will include all `.c` files then you can compile this final using `gcc -c final.c` command.

or

Another method is to use archive.Build all files to get respective `.o` then archive then in one library which will have all those `.o` file.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
gcc -o final file1.c file2.c file3.c
```

it works for me.

Comment: This will generate a binary file, which clearly is not what the question ask for (object file). Please review your answer or delete it to not confuse other people.

Comment: This creates 3 object files, and links them into one executable file. Because the object file are separate, the compiler is not able to in-line or otherwise optimise cross-module calls and references.