# Override weak symbols in static library

Tags: c, gcc, ld, unix-ar

I want to make a static .a library for my project from multiple sources, some of them define weak functions and others implements them. Let's say as example I have :

lib1.c :

```c
void defaultHandler()
{
    for(;;);
}
void myHandler() __attribute__((weak, alias ("defaultHandler")));
```

lib2.c :

```c
void myHandler()
{
    /* do my stuff here */
}
```

Then I want to put them into one single library, so that it seems transparent for the end application

```c
$ ar -r libhandlers.a lib1.o lib2.o
```

But there is now 2 symbols `myHandler` in libhandlers :

```c
$ nm libhandlers.a | grep "myHandler"
00000001 W myHandler
00000581 T myHandler
```

And then when using the lib, the weak reference is linked. The only solution I have for the moment is to not include in the library `lib2.c` but to add it as source in the application's Makefile… that's not satisfying since I would like to provide only a few libraries to use and not a whole bunch of files.

The `--whole-archive` option is also not satisfying since I work on embedded system and I don't want to include all things I don't need.

Is there a way to compile the library so that the weak symbol disappear if a strong one is provided?

NOTE : I'm using arm-none-eabi-gcc v4.8

Answer (score 13):

This is a byproduct of the way that `.a` libraries work - they're simply a collection of `.o` files.

What happens at compile link time is that the first reference to the name gets resolved to the weak reference and the strong name never gets a look in.

You can test this yourself by actually making both the identical name and strong and you'll see exactly the same behaviour.

If you want the strong references resolved first, then put them earlier in the archive, or create a separate strong archive and link that first in the link-line.

While not directly applicable to your case, as you're using an embedded environment, weak vs. strong references come into force properly when creating/consuming `.so` dynamic libraries rather than `.a` archives. When you create a .so, all the weak references that make up the library will not generate an error, and only one of them will be used for the final product; and if there is a strong definition anywhere then it gets used rather than any of the weak ones (this only works properly if, when you're creating a `.so`, you link all the `.o` files that make it up separately, or use the `--whole-archive` when creating the `.so` if linking to a `.a`).

Comment: I don't think using shared libraries is possible on embedded system (basically no operating system)

Comment: @Quentin The last paragraph was a short 'when the weak/strong resolution occurs'. I'll reword the paragraph

Comment: From what you explain, it should be possible to solve the problem by doing a unique .o file from `lib1.c` and `lib2.c` and then put it in the .a (along with others .o files), am I right?

Comment: @Quentin it boils down to a link ordering issue - when using a `.a`, if you ensure that all the strong definitions appear before the weak ones then you'll get the desired behaviour of your library taking the strong definitions before the weak ones. That means either moving them within the archive or ensuring that the archive is created with the `.o` files added in the order that you want - so in this trivial example when you created the archive you would have made it using: `ar rc libhandlers.a lib2.o lib1.o`

Comment: I don't believe you can create a single `.o` from both `.c` files - the compiler will produce individual `.o` files for each `.c` if you compile using `-c`

Comment: changing the order of .o files when making the .a library didn't help. But I think I got the solution with this trick : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18182291/2087834

Comment: If you've got a pre-existing archive, then using `ar -r` won't change their order, you would need to use `ar m` to move them around

Comment: The `--whole-archive` ... `--no-whole-archive` linker options might help here. See [http://winfred-lu.blogspot.de/2009/11/understand-weak-symbols-by-examples.html]