# How to replace a symbol in static library with by attribute weak

Tags: c++, weak-symbol

Suppose I have such code:

lib.h:

```
void func();
```

lib.cpp:

```
void __attribute__((weak)) func()
{
    printf("original");
}
```

and these code would be compile into `libA.a`.

```
clang++ lib.cpp -o libA.a
```

Then in my test unit I want to override this `func` function such as:

test.cpp:

```
#include "lib.h"
void func()
{
    printf("override");
}
```

And:

```
clang++ test.cpp -lA
```

But in my result the output is always `original`.

What is the right way to `weak` a static lib function and then override it externally?

Comment: Looks like a dupe of either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079997/override-weak-symbols-in-static-library and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089166/how-to-make-gcc-link-strong-symbol-in-static-library-to-overwrite-weak-symbol