# Turning symbol weak at link time to resolve multiple definitions

Tags: c++, exception, clang

I am trying to decrease the binary size by overriding default `__terminate_handler`. Normally, when compiling with GCC, this piece of code:

```
[[noreturn]] void terminate() noexcept
{
    while (true)
        ;
}

namespace __cxxabiv1
{
std::terminate_handler __terminate_handler = terminate;
}
```

Makes the default `__terminate_handler` overridden and the binary size decreases by 30-50 kB, depending on the release/debug build type.

When compiling with Clang I use `-nostdlib` linker flag, thus I have to link the standard libraries explicitly, by putting `-lstdc++ -lgcc` as the command line options. This means that I get an error:

> ld.lld: error: duplicate symbol: __cxxabiv1::__terminate_handler
> ->  defined in armgnutoolchain-src/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/libstdc++.a(eh_term_handler.o)
> ->  defined in custom_terminate.cpp.obj

Both, custom code and `libstdc++` define `__cxxabiv1::__terminate_handler` (`_ZN10__cxxabiv119__terminate_handlerE`) as a symbol initialized in data section. Ideally, I would like the symbol to be defined weak in the `libstdc++`.

Is there a way to ignore the symbol defined in `libstdc++`?

Comment: [OT]: `while (true);` is UB.

Comment: It is ugly, but maybe it is possible to modify libstdc++ by adding your `__terminate_handler` before the one in the library (I guess it should be possible with `ar`, but I have not checked the details). The linker should then choose your version and ignore the other. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079997/override-weak-symbols-in-static-library.