# gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-combine’

Tags: c++, node.js, gcc, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile lode library from [here](https://github.com/networkimprov/lode).
However when running make on the yajl.o source I end up with the error:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-combine’
```

I am using 4.9.2 gcc on ubuntu 12.04. I also tried gcc 4.8.1 on different pc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `-combine` was [removed](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2010-09/msg01322.html) in GCC 4.6. However, there is a PR to fix this for `lode` [here](https://github.com/networkimprov/lode/pull/3).