# allocate_shared with malloc

Tags: c++, c++11, memory

I am trying to write a program on
C++ but without using libstdc++.
My program uses some header-only
templates, and also it uses allocate_shared,
to which I supply the custom allocator
to avoid operators new and delete.

My problem is that I can only get
rid of operator new. Operator delete
is still referenced in the resulting
object file.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

template <class T>
struct Mallocator {
  typedef T value_type;
  Mallocator() = default;
  template <class U> constexpr Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&) noexcept {}
  T* allocate(std::size_t n) {
    return (T*)std::malloc(n*sizeof(T));
  }
  void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t) noexcept { std::free(p); }
};
template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(const Mallocator<T>&, const Mallocator<U>&) { return true; }
template <class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const Mallocator<T>&, const Mallocator<U>&) { return false; }

struct A {
    std::shared_ptr<int> a;
    A(const std::shared_ptr<int> b) : a(b) {}
};

int main()
{
    A a(std::allocate_shared<int>(Mallocator<int>(), 5));
    return 0;
}
```

Lets compile:

`$ c++ -c malloca.cpp`

And see what's there:

```
$ nm -u malloca.o | c++filt | grep new
$ nm -u malloca.o | c++filt | grep delete
U operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
```

Operator delete is still there, despite
the custom allocator being provided. How
can I get rid of it?

Comment: "I am trying to write a program on C++ but without using libstdc++" - Why? This seems, on the surface, like a very silly/stupid thing to do. Please explain *why* you are doing this.

Comment: consider for the sake of discussion that you're relying on functionality that might itself have to allocate. That functionality could be using `new` and `delete`. That said this seems very silly.

Comment: @JesperJuhl for example, because libstdc++ is not available on target platform?

Comment: What is the point of this exercise? Tell me it's not a benighted instructor's assignment. Even if standard lib is not available on the platform, there's no reason not to use `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @SergeyA if that was the case I very much would expect OP to have stated that up front.

Comment: You can override globals `::operator new` and `::operator delete` if that helps. Please answer, "What's the point?"

Comment: You're soaking in it. Chances border on 100% that `new` and `delete` are based on `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: Firstly, I suspect this may be a bug.
I wouldn't normally expect delete to be referenced
if the custom allocator/deallocator is provided.
Secondly, what I do is a small templated wrapper
that I plug into a purely C program where size matters.
I'd like to get zero overhead, and linking with
libstdc++ just for the _dead_ operator delete looks
quite useless.
And yes, overriding global operator delete works.
Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: http://www.avabodh.com/cxxin/nostdlib.html
I followed all suggestions of this article.
I really assume that working w/o a standard
library is perfectly fine and supported.

Comment: @stsp only in very limited cases, but most language features are not available because the runtime is not initialized without the stdlib present.

Comment: @Mgetz I expect all language features to be
available (modulo RTTI and exceptions that I
explicitly disabled), and most of the STL, too, as they are
header-only.
This worked very well (i.e. templates, polymorphism, STL -
all worked) till I started to use memory management.
So its really not something unusual. Its still quite feature-rich
and should work properly.

Comment: @stsp a 'freestanding' use of C++ only has access to a few headers: `<cstddef>` `<cstdint>` and I think three others that don't depend on any runtime. Anything depending on runtime: RTTI, exceptions, all require a runtime environment which would require libstdc++ or libc++. Alternatively you can supply your own implementations, which some OS kernel developers have done. https://wiki.osdev.org/C++ has more information on freestanding environment requirements.

Comment: @Mgetz your understanding contradicts with an
article that I referred to above. Here it is again:
avabodh.com/cxxin/nostdlib.html
I think "freestanding" use is a bit more restricted
than what I do. It assumes you have no standard libraries
at all, neither libc nor libstdc++. My use is to have
libc and all STL headers. So its really much richer
than freestanding would allow.

Answer (score 3):

I believe, the call of `operator delete` there is a peculiarity of GCC STL implementation.

Looking at the (rather convoluted) code of `shared_ptr_base.h`, I can see that `_Sp_counted_base` will call `delete` from it's `_M_destroy` function. This function is overridden in `_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace` (the one you end up using with `allocate_shared`), so this code is never executed. But it's presence there provides unresolved symbol.

Overriding global `operator delete` get's rid of it.

Comment: Thanks. I provided an empty inline version of operator
delete and added -Wno-inline-new-delete - that helped.
Still I wonder if it is unsolvable by some other means, like
dead code elimination or the like...

Comment: @stsp you need to look into a "standalone" build, that will block you from using almost all the stdlib however. It's generally used to build operating system kernels.

Comment: @stsp dead code elimination might help, but for this you need to use the link time optimization. I never used it myself, but here is one SO question I found with quick search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688069/requirements-to-use-flto

Comment: Does anyone think this may be a bug worth
reporting to the glibc or gcc team? My feeling is that
the never used, overloaded call should not
propagate to the final object. But I don't know
who should be responsible for this, libstdc++
itself or the compiler's optimizer? Maybe libstdc++
should have used std::enable_if to conditionalize
it, or is it a task of the dead code elimination?
I am coming from an assumption that if you explicitly
want to disable libstdc++, you have guidelines and
compiler options to do exactly that. But in this particular
case they don't work as expected.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a bug in libstdc++ at all (where is the bug??) and as for compiler, lack of optimization is never a bug. You can switch to Clang and it's own libc++.

Comment: The bug can be suspected if working w/o
libstdc++ is a valid and supported scenario,
which I assume it is. Then it is obviously a
bug as this scenario doesn't work. If this is
not supported then its just a missing optimization.
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ produces
the same problem.

Comment: This is weird. When I examined libc++ implementation, I didn't find the delete call. However, I might have missed it, I never want for the full experiment. As for the bug, I am not sure if it is supported scenario.