# G++ issues "storage class specified" errors when using extern inline

Tags: c++, g++, lto

I use link-time optimization (`-flto` in `g++` and `ld` command lines) and some of my method declarations (in headers) are marked as `extern inline` (and just `inline` in `.cpp` files). Compiling yields:

```
./Client/include/GVGLObjects.hpp:96:32: error: storage class specified for 'VertexBuffer'
             EFAST VertexBuffer();
                                ^
```

and a bunch of similar errors for other methods and functions. `EFAST` means `extern inline`.

Why is this happening with LTO enabled? If this isn't allowed, how do I separate declaration and definition with inline and LTO?

Comment: There is no such thing as "extern line" in C++, [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216510/extern-inline). So, just get rid of it, and let the compiler and linker do their job.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "extern **in**line" I think you mean?

Comment: If it's in a header mark it as inline, extern makes no sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extern inline` exists in C, not in C++, though many compilers permit it as an extension ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216546/560648)).

Presumably whatever mechanism and file format GCC uses to perform LTO ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31688314/560648)) is not compatible with this non-standard thing. [The documentation for `-flive-patching=level`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) is interesting, because it describes stuff relating to inlining and storage classes, and tells us that some of it is not available when using LTO (though the actual `-flto` description doesn't specifically call out the `extern inline` extension).

You probably do not want this `EFAST` macro in C++ code.

Comment: Unfortunately, replacing `EFAST` with `FAST` (`inline`) yields the same result.

Comment: @VladislavToncharov That cannot be so. The shown error message only makes sense when a storage class is specified, which you now claim not to be doing.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Looked at the wrong log by accident; of course it doesn't. Instead it just says "inline function used but never defined", and the linker throws "undefined reference".

Comment: @VladislavToncharov Then we're going to need a [mcve] but this is a new question.

Comment: [Here it is.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220421/g-and-lto-how-to-separate-declaration-and-definition "G++ and LTO: how to separate declaration and definition?")