# G++ and LTO: how to separate declaration and definition?

Tags: c++, g++, inline, lto

Since LTO can resolve `inline` symbols from other object files, I tried to separate declaration and definition for `inline` functions. Here is the 3 files, `dep.hpp`, `dep.cpp` and `main.cpp`, where `main.cpp` and `dep.cpp` are linked together and `dep.hpp` is `#include`d in both:

```cpp
// dep.hpp, declaration
#ifndef _DEP_HPP_
#define _DEP_HPP_
inline void sayHello();
#endif

// dep.cpp, definition
#include "dep.hpp"
#include <iostream>

inline void sayHello() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}

// main.cpp, caller
#include "dep.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    sayHello();
}
```

And here's the error that G++ prints:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
dep.hpp: At global scope:
dep.hpp:4:13: warning: inline function 'void sayHello()' used but never defined
 inline void sayHello();
             ^~~~~~~~
C:\Users\vtonc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccojskQy.ltrans0.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `sayHello()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The command line:

```
@echo off
g++ main.cpp dep.cpp -o example.exe -flto -Wall -Wextra
pause
```

Why is the linker complaining about undefined `sayHello()` when `-flto` is enabled and `sayHello()` itself is `inline`? Shouldn't LTO handle such cases?

I'm using mingw-w64 8.1.0 `x86_64-posix-seh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of `inline` is that you must provide the function's definition in the same translation unit(s) in which you call the function.

Turning on a compiler optimisation doesn't change that; it's a rule of the language.

Move the definition to the header.