# Making relocatable object with gcc causes "cannot find -lgcc_s" error

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

I'm trying to make a relocatable object file with *gcc*. I use solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2980126/5447906). The solution works fine with *ld*:

```
$ ld -r a.o b.o -o c.o
```

However when I try to use it with *gcc*, the following error happens:

```
$ gcc -r a.o b.o -o c.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Using the `-Wl,-r` and `-Wl,--relocatable` options gives the same result.

Is there any way to link relocatable object file with *gcc* or I'm forced to use *ld* for doing this?

Comment: You need to tell gcc not to use any standard libraries. Frankly I don't understand the need. Use ld, that's what it's for.

Comment: I'm composing a command that makes output file from the set of object files. I want to make it universal, so it can produce executables, shared libraries and relocatable objects depending on output filename extension. I use _g++_ for making executables and shared libraries, wanted to use it for making relocatable objects too. And I'm not sure that extra _gcc_ flags passed as parameter to my command will be valid for _ld_.

Comment: Your universal solution has to select program options depending on the extension. Might select the program itself as well. `gcc` is as different from `ld` as from `gcc -shared`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, the `-nostdlib` option must also be passed to *gcc*:

```
$ gcc -r -nostdlib a.o b.o -o c.o
```

I don't know it for sure, but it seems without this option *gcc* tries to link standard libraries into output relocatable object.

Comment: The `-nostartfiles` option may be useful too.