# Do I need to specify an indirectly-used library to the compiler?

Tags: c, gcc

If a C program uses a library `A` (`.a` or `.so`), and the library `A` uses another library `B` (`.a` or `.so`), when I compile the C program, do I have to specify the path to the header and the library file of library `B` to a compiler such as `gcc`?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the libraries and your program. If your program is indirectly/transitively including headers from `B`, then yeah, you'll need the header path. Depending on how the `A` library was built and linked, you may or may not need to explicitly link to the `B` library as well.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on "Depending on how the A library was built and linked, you may or may not need to explicitly link to the B library as well."?

Comment: Generally, if `A` is a shared library, you typically don't need to pass `B` to the linker. For static libraries, It's possible to pre-link `A`. Or you can make `A` be a composite/conglomerate library (so it includes `B`). Or you can not do anything fancy and require `B` be passed to the linker when using `A`.

Comment: Thanks. (1) "if A is a shared library, you typically don't need to pass B to the linker." How can B be found? (2) What is "pre-link A"? (3) How can you  "make A be a composite/conglomerate library (so it includes B)"?

Comment: (1) If B is a static library, it's already linked into A. If B is a dynamic library, then A can specify that it links to it (and where to find it) (try running `ldd` (Linux) or `otool -L` (macOS) on a shared library to see what it links to). (2) You can link A's and B's [.o files into a single .o file with `ld -r`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2980102/1287251). (3) Use a thin archive, or [a little `ar` script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3821916/1287251#comment36843318_23621751).

Answer (score 0):

> do I have to specify the path to the header

This depends if the header (`#include`) file of library A contains an `#include` line which includes the header file of library B.

Most developers of libraries try to avoid this so you can even use library A if you do not have the header files of library B!

(Which of course means that you do not have to specify the path to the header files.)

> and the library file of library B to a compiler such as gcc?

- If library A is a static library (`.a`) you definitely have to specify library B:

  It does not matter if library B is static (`.a`) or shared (`.so`). However if library B is static (`.a`) and uses a library C you also have to specify library C. And if library C uses a library D...
- If library A is a shared library (`.so`) it depends on the operating system used:

  - Using very, very old Linux variants (late 1990s) you had to specify library B (and library C ...).
  - Maybe there are still operating systems which have this behaviour.
  - Under recent Linux variants you don't have to specify library B if library A is a shared library. The same is true for (all versions of?) Windows.